# why can't I add a member to an ADobject

Tags: powershell, active-directory

If I have an object of type Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject, I can't use Add-Member to add a note property, unless I use -force. If I don't use the force directive, I get an error like:

> Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "SAMAccountName"
>   because a member with that name already exists. To overwrite the
>   member anyway, add the Force parameter to your command.

But, it doesn't already exist. And that happens for any property name. For example:

```
$domainAccount | Add-Member -NotePropertyName SAMAccountName -NotePropertyValue $account.name
```

But, this works:

```
$domainAccount | Add-Member -NotePropertyName SAMAccountName -NotePropertyValue $account.name -force
```

I can't find documentation that explains this. Can you explain it? And, is there any danger in doing this with the -force directive?

Comment: "*But, it doesn't already exist.*" - do I believe the PowerShell runtime, or you? What evidence do you have that it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ADObject` class behaves a bit clumsy, in that by simply *asking* if a property exists, you cause the property to be created if it doesn't.

When `Add-Member` checks for whether the `SAMAccountName` property already exists, it incidentally cause it to be created.

Just use the `-Force` parameter switch.

---

You can reproduce this behavior yourself:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ADObject = New-Object Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject

# No SamAccountName property will be listed
$ADObject | Get-Member
```

Now, try to reference a non-existing property, like "SamAccountName" (the ADObject extends the `ADPropertyValueCollection` class which is basically a dictionary, so indexing into it's property is totally valid):

```
$ADObject["SamAccountName"]
# SamAccountName property will now be listed even though we haven't set it
$ADObject | Get-Member
```

This is not restricted to AD property names, anything goes:

```
"1 This","2 Is","3 Quite","4 Funky","5 Isn't","6 It?" |ForEach-Object {
    [void]$ADObject[$_]
}

$ADObject |Get-Member
```

[image: It sure is!]

Comment: I find `Add-Member` to be a bit weird, especially when used in loops, so even if you only add a property to each item, you end up having to use `-Force` anyway. As a result, I just always call it with `-Force` now.

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject** already have **SamAccountName** property. You don't need to recreate it. Just need define value for it, like this:

```
$obj = New-Object Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject
$obj.SamAccountName = 'AccountName'
$obj | Get-Member
```

Output:

```
TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject

Name           MemberType            Definition                                                                             
----           ----------            ----------                                                                             
Contains       Method                bool Contains(string propertyName)                                                     
Equals         Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                         
GetEnumerator  Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()                               
GetHashCode    Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                      
GetType        Method                type GetType()                                                                         
ToString       Method                string ToString()                                                                      
Item           ParameterizedProperty Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection Item(string propertyN...
SamAccountName Property              Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection SamAccountName {get;s...
```

Comment: If you pipe `$obj` to `Get-Member` *before* setting `SamAccountName`, you'll see that it doesn't already exist